# install apps from ubuntu livecd

Tags: linux, ubuntu, livecd

I was running the other day an ubuntu cdlive and something drew my attention. I installed a few apps and they seemed to have been installed on the disk. What I wonder now is, where are these apps actually installed? I guess they can't have been installed on the DVD-R from which a ran ubuntu.
Will the new apps be there the next time a run the livecd? If not, is there any possibility to save the changes made to the file system?

Comment: No idea about live cd, but on Live USB you can have persistent software install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I wonder now is, where are these apps actually installed?

They are installed to the virtual system in the ram. When you boot up a live CD, it copies most of the system files to ram (at least, thats how I understood it as).

> Will the new apps be there the next time a run the livecd?

No, just like your files on the live system they will go into the virtual ether.

> If not, is there any possibility to save the changes made to the file system?

I remember a tool in trisquel that did that..., you had to have two CD drives, or a place to save the .iso, though...

You could try this http://www.remastersys.com/

Comment: some further reading: <http://lifehacker.com/5588211/how-to-create-your-own-customized-ubuntu-live-cd>, <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_disk> and <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD>